# What are the differences between the exponential growth equation that involves calculus and the one that does not?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why aren't $y=y_0e^{kt}$ and $y=y_0(1+k)^t$ the same?

For half life problems in particular, interestingly, $y=y_0e^{\frac{-tln2}{T_{1/2}}}$ and $y=y_0(1/2)^{t/T_{1/2}}$ turn out to be the same?

EDIT

y(t) gives you the number after time t of an exponentially growing "thing". $y_0$ is the number of things at t=0. K is the relative growth rate: $k=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{y}$.

Both of the latter formulas I learned before taking calculus...

Comment: For the first you assume *continuous* growth, and for the second, *discrete* growth.

Comment: What parts of it tell you it's discrete? Can't I put a decimal for t?

Comment: Maybe you can provide some details on the models and the assumptions, and some description on the meanings of the variables.

Comment: What exactly do you ask for?

Comment: What does $y(t)$ model? What does $t$ represent? What are $y_0$ and $k$?

Comment: The former applies to the differential equation $y'(t)=ky(t)$ (with $t$ some real number) while the latter applies to the difference equation $y_{n+1}-y_n=ky_n$ (with $n$ some integer). Thus, the context makes it clear which one is relevant. (Of course, writing $y$ in both cases instead of $y(t)$ or $y_n$ is a first step towards confusion...)

Comment: @Did, but what does the subscript (n) mean? What is the time interval between n and n+1? Also, when you solve for $y_n+1$ in terms of $y_n$, where does the variable t comes in?

Comment: Again, there are two classes of models and one class uses *sequences indexed by the integers*, in your case sequences $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ determined by an initial condition $y_0$ and by a difference equation $y_{n+1}-y_n=ky_n$. Then there is no time $t$ involved, in the sense of some continuous parameter the quantity of interest would depend on. Instead, one has $y_n=(1+k)^ny_0$ *for every nonnegative integer $n$*. Thus $y_n$ could correspond to the quantity of interest after $n$ hours (but only for an integer number $n$ of hours)..